# File system error :windows 10 task manager

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update, task-manager

Recently i updated windows 10 build and once the update have been applied myself getting weird error :

[image]

As per the [microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/file-system-error-1073741819-on-windows-10/30f76ed6-bac1-4863-bfc0-fddb746af898?auth=1) answer ,registry edit should fix the issue

but while accessing registry editor :

[image]

The possible solutions were :

Refresh the windows 10 pc and creating new user account which sounds impossible right now

anyother solution to get my taskmanager and registry editor back :

right now i could access command prompt with admin privilege through system32 folder

anything could i do to resolve it?

My windows version details are as follows :

[image]

while i try to run command through windows search(win+q) ,search cmd ,right click run as admin

it gives the following error :

[image]

While i manually browsed and executed system 32 folder :

[image]

unable to getinto sfc /scannow method it sounds weird anyother options?

Comment: What build of Windows are you running exactly?  Your first statement sort of indicates you have opted into the Insider Preview.  Please clarify this statement.   You are going to need to do a better job of indicating what your question is exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound windows 10 enterprise bro ,updated snapshot of my winver command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too and found the solution via a post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f27ko/tech_windows_10_file_system_error/culgllu

This linked to the following page: http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/08/file-system-error-1073741819.html?m=1

As the page points out, the culprit is your Sound Scheme. It *seems* that when upgrading, the scheme I had went lost, and it is actually complaining about not finding the sound for the UAC dialog / admin prompt, so instead of just not playing the sound, it falls over. (Well, that's my interpretation, I didn't read through everything, but the main thing is it solved the problem).

So after going to Control Panel > Sound > Sounds (tab) and switching the Sound Scheme to Windows Default, everything is working.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would try is the System File checker.

From an administrative command prompt run:
sfc /scannow

More info on it here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @brian lewis it doesnt work friend,i have updated question

Comment: @Ramhound bro the command prompt cant run sfcscannow command bro :(

Comment: You didn't indicate that in the original revision.  Have you tried logging into the default Administrator user and then running the command?